# Remove Matching Paragraphs From File By Searching Another File

Tags: linux, perl, shell, sed, awk

I need help with a script which takes 2 Files as Input:

```
File1: [TEXT] contains Paragraphs SEPARATED with BLANK LINES
File2: [SEARCH KEYS] Paragraphs SEPARATED with BLANK LINES
```

and creates an Output File: File3 - which contains TEXT from File1 EXCEPT those PARAGRAPHS which EXACTLY MATCHES with those provided in File2.

i.e. The Script needs to search Each Paragraph Given in File1 -- in File2. IF a PERFECT MATCH (with ALL MATCHING LINES) is found, drop the Matching Paragraph from Output File3.

Given: 2 Files

```
File1:

PARA1_LINE1
PARA1_LINE2
PARA1_LINE3

PARA2_LINE1
PARA2_LINE2

PARA1_LINE1
PARA1_LINE2
PARA1_LINE3

File2:

PARA1_LINE1
PARA1_LINE2
PARA1_LINE3

PARA2_LINE1
```

Required Output:

```
File3:

PARA2_LINE1
PARA2_LINE2
```

Note: The Second Paragraph [PARA2] is NOT a complete Match, hence it should not be ommited from File 3

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing the input record separator [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to process in paragraph mode.  Note, I didn't [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) since the last record might have only a single return.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

if (@ARGV != 2) {
    print "Usage: $0 [Text File] [Search Key File]\n";
    exit;
}

my $file1 = shift;

local $/ = "\n\n";

my %para;
while (<>) {
    s/\n+$//;
    $para{$_} = 1;
}

local @ARGV = $file1;
while (<>) {
    s/\n+$//;
    print $_,$/ if ! $para{$_};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` should work:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

- We turn the paragraph mode on by setting `RS` variable.
- We load the entire paragraph as key to array `a` from file2.
- If the paragraph is **not** found in file1 we print it.

```
$ cat file1
PARA1_LINE1
PARA1_LINE2
PARA1_LINE3

PARA2_LINE1
PARA2_LINE2

PARA1_LINE1
PARA1_LINE2
PARA1_LINE3
```

```
$ cat file2
PARA1_LINE1
PARA1_LINE2
PARA1_LINE3

PARA2_LINE1
```

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1
PARA2_LINE1
PARA2_LINE2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this script doesn't preserve the "space" between paragraphs - in final output. Example: if PARA1_... entries are not found & needed to be printed, 6 entries are printed without space. Hence, paragraph separators are lost !

Comment: @SandeepSingh Thats can be fixed easily by setting the `ORS` variable to `\n\n`. Check the updated solution.